# Como marcar um item especifico de um CheckBoxList com jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Tenho visto vários exemplos de como marcar e desmarcar todos, mas não vi como marcar um especifico, veja:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkAcoesListarGrupo" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Novo</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Atualizar</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Excluir</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Visualizar</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">Pesquisar</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Como faço para deixar o item `Visualizar` marcado com **jquery** ?

Seria algo assim:

```
$('#<%= ddlPerfil.ClientID %>').change(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
//Aqui eu marcaria o item **Visualizar**
});
```

Comment: Pq vc simplesmente não coloca no checkbox que vc quer deixar marcado o atributo `checked ` ?

Comment: @hugocsl desse jeito `$("[id*=chkAcoesListarGrupo] input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);` eu marco e/ou desmarco todos da lista mas como faço para atribuir `checked` sosmente para o item `Visualizar` ?

Answer (score 1):

Com jQuery vc pode checar um `checkbox` dessa forma `.prop('checked', true)`, usando o atributo value `$('[value="teste"]')`

Veja o exemplo funcionando.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $('[value="teste"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn">clicar</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="teste" value="teste">

<p>vc tb pode deixar marcado direto no load, <i>"$(document).ready(function(){ "</i></p>
```

---

**Via HTML**

Não sei se é exatamente isso que vc precisa mas pq não usa o atributo `checked` do html? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked

Veja esse exemplo:

```html
<div class="btns">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">item 1<br>
  <input checked type="checkbox" name="" id="">checado<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">item 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="">item 4<br>
</div>
```

Comment: eu posso ter a seguinte situação: `<input type="checkbox" name="" id="teste" value="teste">; <input type="checkbox" name="" id="teste_1" value="teste">; <input type="checkbox" name="" id="teste_2" value="teste">;`

Comment: no evento jaquery como vou distinguir qual checkbox ?

Comment: Se todos tem o mesmo Valeu e ID diferente ai vc pega pelo ID, simples assim `$('[id="teste_1"]')` que seria simplificado `$('#teste_1')`.

Comment: @adrianojc Vc tb pode pegar na "grosseria o segundo item da lista dessa forma, caso todos tenham o mesmo `value`, ai o segundo item que tenha o mesmo `value` vc aplica o checked... `$('[value="teste"]:nth-of-type(2)')` onde vc vê o número 2 é a posição do item na lista, se tiver 4 itens e vc quiser selecionar o Quarto item vc faria `$('[value="teste"]:nth-of-type(4)')`